# How to refresh include (inc) file

Tags: 8

I updated an include (inc) file. It was a text change. I want my website to show these changes. I cleared the cache. Nothing changed. I restarted the server. Nothing changed. I checked the server. The new include (inc) file is there. Not sure how else to refresh the include (inc) file.
It's located at htdocs\sites\all\modules\custom\myMods

Here is the new file: ( I simply changed the text in the  of the description )

```
<?php
/**
 * @file
 * siam_team_profile.field_group.inc
 */

/**
 * Implements hook_field_group_info().
 */
function siam_team_profile_field_group_info() {
  $field_groups = array();

  $field_group = new stdClass();
  $field_group->disabled = FALSE; /* Edit this to true to make a default field_group disabled initially */
  $field_group->api_version = 1;
  $field_group->identifier = 'group_parcon|node|team_member|form';
  $field_group->group_name = 'group_parcon';
  $field_group->entity_type = 'node';
  $field_group->bundle = 'team_member';
  $field_group->mode = 'form';
  $field_group->parent_name = '';
  $field_group->data = array(
    'label' => 'Parental Consent',
    'weight' => '7',
    'children' => array(
      0 => 'field_consent',
      1 => 'field_name_of_parent',
      2 => 'field_ethnicity',
    ),
    'format_type' => 'fieldset',
    'format_settings' => array(
      'label' => 'Parental Consent',
      'instance_settings' => array(
        'required_fields' => 1,
        'classes' => 'group-pconsent field-group-fieldset',
        'description' => '<p><strong>The section below is to be filled out by the student’s parent or guardian.</strong></p>

<div> 
By agreeing to this Parent/Guardian Consent statement, I give my permission for my son/daughter to participate in  <i>MATLAB Math Modeling Challenge</i>, which is funded by The MathWorks and organized and administered by the Society for Industrial and Applied Mathematics (SIAM). I give my permission to disclose his/her name and likeness in text, still pictures, and in videos, for publication in press releases, on the M3Challenge and MathWorks* websites, and in SIAM News. I also give my permission to release his/her name and likeness to any and all online or print local, regional, or national newspapers, radio and television outlets, and via any other media, including social media platforms, that seek to publicize the Challenge and its participants in any way. <br /><br />

On behalf of myself and my child, I hereby (a) waive any right or cause of action arising as a result of his/her participation in the Challenge and (b) release and discharge MathWorks and SIAM from any and all claims or causes of action (known or unknown) arising out of his/her participation in the Challenge (including, but not limited to, its or their negligence). <br /><br />

I understand that for teams proceeding to the final competition process, the students\' live presentations at the final Challenge event will be photographed and/or videotaped, and these photos and videos may be used for webcast, broadcast, posting to the M3 Challenge website, in news releases, and in the media, as well as in internal or external SIAM or MathWorks publications, online or in print, and on any SIAM or MathWorks Internet websites and digital social media presence, and I consent to any and all such use. <br /><br />

*MathWorks includes The MathWorks, Incany and all of its product lines, affiliates, subsidiaries, and their successors and assigns, and any and all of their past and present directors, officers, representatives, agents and employees, whether as individuals or in their official capacity.
</div>',
      ),
      'formatter' => 'collapsible',
    ),
  );
  $field_groups['group_parcon|node|team_member|form'] = $field_group;

  $field_group = new stdClass();
  $field_group->disabled = FALSE; /* Edit this to true to make a default field_group disabled initially */
  $field_group->api_version = 1;
  $field_group->identifier = 'group_personal|node|team_member|form';
  $field_group->group_name = 'group_personal';
  $field_group->entity_type = 'node';
  $field_group->bundle = 'team_member';
  $field_group->mode = 'form';
  $field_group->parent_name = '';
  $field_group->data = array(
    'label' => 'Personal Information',
    'weight' => '0',
    'children' => array(
      0 => 'field_first_name',
      1 => 'field_gender',
      2 => 'field_grade',
      3 => 'field_teamail',
      4 => 'title',
    ),
    'format_type' => 'fieldset',
    'format_settings' => array(
      'formatter' => 'collapsible',
      'instance_settings' => array(
        'description' => '',
        'classes' => 'group-personal field-group-fieldset',
        'required_fields' => 1,
      ),
    ),
  );
  $field_groups['group_personal|node|team_member|form'] = $field_group;

  // Translatables
  // Included for use with string extractors like potx.
  t('Parental Consent');
  t('Personal Information');

  return $field_groups;
}
```

Old file for reference:

```
            <?php
    /**
     * @file
     * siam_team_profile.field_group.inc
     */

    /**
     * Implements hook_field_group_info().
     */
    function siam_team_profile_field_group_info() {
      $field_groups = array();

      $field_group = new stdClass();
      $field_group->disabled = FALSE; /* Edit this to true to make a default field_group disabled initially */
      $field_group->api_version = 1;
      $field_group->identifier = 'group_parcon|node|team_member|form';
      $field_group->group_name = 'group_parcon';
      $field_group->entity_type = 'node';
      $field_group->bundle = 'team_member';
      $field_group->mode = 'form';
      $field_group->parent_name = '';
      $field_group->data = array(
        'label' => 'Parental Consent',
        'weight' => '7',
        'children' => array(
          0 => 'field_consent',
          1 => 'field_name_of_parent',
          2 => 'field_ethnicity',
        ),
        'format_type' => 'fieldset',
        'format_settings' => array(
          'label' => 'Parental Consent',
          'instance_settings' => array(
            'required_fields' => 1,
            'classes' => 'group-pconsent field-group-fieldset',
            'description' => '<p><strong>The section below is to be filled out by the student’s parent or guardian.</strong></p>

    <div>
    By agreeing to this Parent/Guardian Consent statement, I give my permission for my son/daughter to participate in Moody\'s Mega Math (M<sup>3</sup>) Challenge, which is funded by The Moody\'s Foundation and organized and administered by the Society for Industrial and Applied Mathematics (SIAM). I give my permission to disclose his/her name and likeness in text, still pictures, and in videos, for publication in press releases, on the M<sup>3</sup> Challenge and Moody\'s* websites, and in SIAM News. I also give my permission to release his/her name and likeness to any and all online or print local, regional, or national newspapers, radio and television outlets, and via any other media, including social media platforms, that seek to publicize the Challenge and its participants in any way.<br /><br />

    On behalf of myself and my child, I hereby (a) waive any right or cause of action arising as a result of his/her participation in the Challenge and (b) release and discharge Moody\'s and SIAM from any and all claims or causes of action (known or unknown) arising out of his/her participation in the Challenge (including, but not limited to, its or their negligence).<br /><br />

    I understand that for teams proceeding to the final competition process, the students\' presentations at Moody\'s headquarters in Manhattan will be photographed and/or videotaped, and these photos and videos may be used for webcast, broadcast, posting to the M<sup>3</sup> Challenge website, in news releases, and in the media, as well as in internal or external SIAM or Moody\'s publications, online or in print, and on any SIAM or Moody\'s Internet websites, and I consent to any and all such use.<br /><br />

    *Moody\'s includes Moody\'s Corporation, and any and all of its affiliates, subsidiaries, and their successors and assigns, and any and all of their past and present directors, officers, representatives, agents and employees, whether as individuals or in their official capacity.
    </div>',
          ),
          'formatter' => 'collapsible',
        ),
      );
      $field_groups['group_parcon|node|team_member|form'] = $field_group;

      $field_group = new stdClass();
      $field_group->disabled = FALSE; /* Edit this to true to make a default field_group disabled initially */
      $field_group->api_version = 1;
      $field_group->identifier = 'group_personal|node|team_member|form';
      $field_group->group_name = 'group_personal';
      $field_group->entity_type = 'node';
      $field_group->bundle = 'team_member';
      $field_group->mode = 'form';
      $field_group->parent_name = '';
      $field_group->data = array(
        'label' => 'Personal Information',
        'weight' => '0',
        'children' => array(
          0 => 'field_first_name',
          1 => 'field_gender',
          2 => 'field_grade',
          3 => 'field_teamail',
          4 => 'title',
        ),
        'format_type' => 'fieldset',
        'format_settings' => array(
          'formatter' => 'collapsible',
          'instance_settings' => array(
            'description' => '',
            'classes' => 'group-personal field-group-fieldset',
            'required_fields' => 1,
          ),
        ),
      );
      $field_groups['group_personal|node|team_member|form'] = $field_group;

      // Translatables
      // Included for use with string extractors like potx.
      t('Parental Consent');
      t('Personal Information');

      return $field_groups;
    }
```

Comment: You tagged the question "8". Sure you are using Drupal 8? Afaik this is a hook from the 7 version of the module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is cache somewhere along the stack so if its not drupal cache

try making a small change on the file that includes this file and saving in order to force renewing the timestamp

or you might want to try

```
//after include
clearstatcache();
```

more info here http://php.net/manual/en/function.clearstatcache.php

or if you have opcache enabled can try to setting it `opcache.enable = 0` or

```
//
opcache_invalidate ( string $script [, boolean $force = FALSE ] )
```

or please tell us how your website is accessed all service running on your server that might be intercepting the generation of the site